# Adjust Navigation Back Button iOS 13

Tags: ios

I've noticed that the default, back button for view controllers embed in a navigation controller does not scale per device size. Is there anyway I'd be able to adjust the font size of the back button depending on the device size?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The back button is a bar button item. *No* bar button item will automatically "scale per device size". You are free to apply your own title text attributes to the back button, just as you would do for any other bar button item:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibaritem/1616414-settitletextattributes

Note, however, that it is not usual to have different text sizes on difference devices, and users might be surprised by it.

Comment: Ok, on the iPad simulator (for example) the back button seemed pretty small, is that normal? @matt

Comment: If you set all simulators to the same relative size (like Actual Size) you’ll see that the button size is the same on all of them.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble, but could you take a look at the newly edited question? The first picture is the back button on the iPad 12.9, and the second picture is the back button on the iPhone 8. Though the back button does not scale in the simulator, it'll look fine on the actual device? @matt

Comment: Sure, well, in that picture you've reduced an iPad to the size of an iPhone so naturally the button text is smaller, just like the status bar text above it. But it just _looks_ smaller because you've made the simulator so small. What's odd in that screenshot is how big the "Droplist" is on the iPad. On a real iPad that's going to be HUGE!!!!! That will look really strange to your users.